# What are the official Star Wars books involving Anakin Skywalker?

Tags: star-wars

Could someone please give me a full list of Star Wars books that are official and involve Anakin Skywalker up to Darth Vader? I need all of them listed please, in order if possible.  Believe it or not I haven't read them yet. If possible, could someone please explain to me if Anakin Skywalker was the only main of the story or not?

Comment: The first part of your question appears to be general reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darth_Vader#Literature . As for the second part, it is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

Anakin Skywalker was kid in 32 BBY (Before Battle of Yavin) which is featured in movie "Star Wars: The Phantom Menace (Episode I)". He was Darth Vader in 0 BBY which is featured in "Star Wars: A New Hope (Episode IV)". So, pick books from [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Wars_books) which feature 32 BBY to 0 BBY.
For your purpose, **"The Rise and Fall of Darth Vader" (by Rydar Windham)** will be great.